# Child div's height is shorter than the parent's, even with height set to 100%

Tags: html, css

I'm using bootstrap and I don't know why a child div's height is shorter on large screen and 100% on small screen. Here's a pciture of what it looks like on large screen [. I want that white space at the bottom gone.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LCGFh.png)I tried setting the height to 100% but it's not working. Here's how it looks like on small screen. [You can notice that as the screen get smaller, the button is hiding behind the section below it.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8G0px.png)

Here's the html

```
<div class="project">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" id="project-description">
                <h3>Project</h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.<br> Nulla pretium varius velit, quis bibendum augue pharetra nec. Integer venenatis ipsum ex, quis euismod dui interdum non. Quisque lobortis magna in risus rutrum, vel dictum nulla pulvinar. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla pretium varius velit, quis bibendum augue pharetra nec. Integer venenatis ipsum ex, quis euismod dui interdum non. Quisque lobortis magna in risus rutrum, vel dictum nulla pulvinar. <br><br><a href="#" class="btn btn-default">More Info</a></p>
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" id="project-picture">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here's the css

```
    .project {
    height: 400px;
}

    .project .container-fluid {
    max-height: 100%;
}

    .project #project-description {
    background-color: #013051;
    max-height: 400px;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: Futura, "Trebuchet MS", Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
}

    .project #project-description h3 {
    margin-top: 60px;
}

    #project-description h3, #project-description p {
    margin-left:40px;
}

    #project-description p {
    border-left: 1px solid #f5f5f5;
    padding-left: 20px;
}

    #project-description p a {
    background-color: #013051;
    border: 1px solid #f5f5f5;
    color: #f5f5f5;
    padding: 10px 30px;
}

    #project-description p a:hover, .contact form button:hover {
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    color: #000;
}

    .project #project-picture {
    background-image: url(file:///C:/Users/Nelson/Desktop/EsperAfrica/Images/jd-mason-43265.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 400px;
}
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: do you have a lin to your website ? imo the problem is the #project-image div is more higher than the other. try to see with your dev tool browser

Answer (score 0):

According to me the problem is that the parent div have some padding and margin. Which is not allowing the div to get its 100% height. Or maybe there could be any problem related bootst